# WooCommerce order bulk edit with custom hooks in function.php

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I'm working on a Wordpress site with WooCommerce. I have to implement some additional functions, one of them is some simple operation after marking the order completed. I use `woocommerce_order_status_completed` hook, like this in functions.php:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed' , 'pontfeliras_woocommerce_order_status_completed',10,2);

function pontfeliras_woocommerce_order_status_completed( $order ) {
    $order = new WC_Order($order);
    $order_id = $order->id;
    $user_id = $order->user_id;
    ...
    boring code here
    ...

    update_field( 'pontertek_felirva', true );
    }
}
```

If I open the order to edit it (by clicking on the order # in admin), then setting order status to Completed makes the function fire exactly I want it to.

But if I try this at the bulk edit section, multiple orders visible --> ticking the checkboxes --> Mark as completed --> Apply then the desired actions won't happen, only the orders get set to completed. Maybe it is related to this part of the code:

```
$order = new WC_Order($order);
```

This part creates objects, like this (using var_dump($order);):

```
object(WC_Order)#9567 (14) {
["order_type"]=&gt;
string(6) "simple"
["id"]=&gt;
int(375)
["post"]=&gt;
object(WP_Post)#9526 (24) {
  ["ID"]=&gt;
  int(375)
  ["post_author"]=&gt;
  string(1) "1"
  ["post_date"]=&gt;
  string(19) "2015-10-11 23:20:00"
  ["post_date_gmt"]=&gt;
  string(19) "2015-10-11 23:20:00"
  ["post_content"]=&gt;
  string(0) ""
  ["post_title"]=&gt;
  string(43) "Order – október 11, 2015 @ 11:20 DU."
  ["post_excerpt"]=&gt;
  string(0) ""
  ["post_status"]=&gt;
  string(12) "wc-completed"
  ["comment_status"]=&gt;
  string(6) "closed"
  ["ping_status"]=&gt;
  string(6) "closed"
  ["post_password"]=&gt;
  string(0) ""
  ["post_name"]=&gt;
  string(29) "order-oktober-11-2015-1120-du"
  ["to_ping"]=&gt;
  string(0) ""
  ["pinged"]=&gt;
  string(0) ""
  ["post_modified"]=&gt;
  string(19) "2015-10-11 23:20:29"
  ["post_modified_gmt"]=&gt;
  string(19) "2015-10-11 23:20:29"
  ["post_content_filtered"]=&gt;
  string(0) ""
  ["post_parent"]=&gt;
  int(0)
  ["guid"]=&gt;
  string(55) "http://flavantic.local/?post_type=shop_order&amp;p=375"
  ["menu_order"]=&gt;
  int(0)
  ["post_type"]=&gt;
  string(10) "shop_order"
  ["post_mime_type"]=&gt;
  string(0) ""
  ["comment_count"]=&gt;
  string(1) "1"
  ["filter"]=&gt;
  string(3) "raw"
}
["order_date"]=&gt;
string(19) "2015-10-11 23:20:00"
["modified_date"]=&gt;
string(19) "2015-10-11 23:20:29"
["customer_message"]=&gt;
string(0) ""
["customer_note"]=&gt;
string(0) ""
["post_status"]=&gt;
string(12) "wc-completed"
["prices_include_tax"]=&gt;
bool(true)
["tax_display_cart"]=&gt;
string(4) "incl"
["display_totals_ex_tax"]=&gt;
bool(false)
["display_cart_ex_tax"]=&gt;
bool(false)
["formatted_billing_address":protected]=&gt;
string(0) ""
["formatted_shipping_address":protected]=&gt;
string(0) ""
}
```

I tried to iterate with foreach loop, but had no success. What should be the solution?